# Handle different event of GCM library?

Tags: c#, android

I am using GCMlibrary in C#. I have implemented different handlers that check whether message is sent or not. How can I check handler that is for

1. ChannelException
2. ChannelDestroyed
3. ServiceException

How can I check when exception come in these events.

I have declared handler like this

```
static void ChannelException(object sender, IPushChannel channel, Exception exception)
    {
        CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.INFO, "Channel Exception: " + sender + " -> " + exception);
        // Console.WriteLine("Channel Exception: " + sender + " -> " + exception);
    }

static void ServiceException(object sender, Exception exception)
    {
        CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.INFO, "Service Exception: " + sender + " -> " + exception);
        string test= exception.Message;
        // Console.WriteLine("Channel Exception: " + sender + " -> " + exception);
    }

static void ChannelDestroyed(object sender)
    {
        CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.INFO, "Channel Destroyed for: " + sender);
        // Console.WriteLine("Channel Destroyed for: " + sender);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle exceptions in events in C# use the sample from MSDN. Use the following events raise approach:

```
public class Pub
{
    public event EventHandler OnChange = delegate { };
    public void Raise()
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        foreach (Delegate handler in OnChange.GetInvocationList())
        {
            try
            {
                handler.DynamicInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }
        if (exceptions.Any())
        {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Catch exceptions as mentioned:

```
public void CreateAndRaise()
{
    Pub p = new Pub();
    p.OnChange += (sender, e)
    => Console.WriteLine(“Subscriber 1 called”);
    p.OnChange += (sender, e)
    => { throw new Exception(); };
    p.OnChange += (sender, e)
    => Console.WriteLine(“Subscriber 3 called”);
    try
    {
        p.Raise();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerExceptions.Count);
    }
    // Displays
    // Subscriber 1 called
    // Subscriber 3 called
    // 1
}
```

If you are unable to change existing event handlers, then:

1. Write your own event handler, which wraps existing, for example `ChannelEventCustom`.
2. In its raise method, wrap existing event execution (for example `ChannelEvent`) in `try-catch` block
3. That's all. Here is [short guide how to create your own events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: my question was not that i have a handler of these events but unable to catch these exectpion. I am using GCm library. These events are defined but i want when these exception will come .